# How can I feed the output of a universal motor (as generator) back into its field coils?

Tags: generator, feedback

I've been playing around with a universal motor to see if I can get it to generate power - with the aim in mind of trying to connect it to a wind turbine in the future.

I have had some success at using it as a separately excited generator, but when it comes to feeding back power into the field coils from the output I am at a bit of a loss as to the best way to proceed.

It doesn't seem to have enough residual magnetism to self start, so I have tried feeding power from output to the field coils both in parallel, once with a 100ohm resistor to try and split the current between the field coils and the load (an LED,) another time with just wire.  I've also tried it in series with the load.

I have read that a universal motor is a series DC motor, so I have cut all the wires from the brushes and added new ones so they are isolated from the field coils.  I confirmed this by my multimeter reading in the mega ohms when measuring the resistance between the brushes and the field coils.

This is the most recent circuit I've been using, but I cannot work out how to get it to keep running once I've disconnected the battery.

[image: Most recent circuit]

Comment: "keep running once I've disconnected the battery" Attach another energy source.  Energy is required, or were you hoping for a perpetual motion machine? If what you want is to have a wind turbine that spins and keeps spinning for a while after the wind has stopped, it needs energy storage; momentum would be likely a more efficient storage than electrical.

Comment: Im turning the rotor on the generator with a another motor

Comment: @Abel:  The universal motor is to be used as a generator.  The battery is there to provide current to the stator so that the motor will have a magnetic field, allowing it to start generating current current as it is turned by the wind or a second motor.

Comment: @Abel: Universal motors don't have permanent magnets for the stator.

Comment: What's providing current to the field coils in your universal motor?

Comment: You might need to add a large electrolytic capacitor in parallel to the field coils to prevent the motor from "latching off" when it commutates. Could you try it with a 4700µF 35V (or similar) cap just to see if that changes things? Also, how much current do the field coils draw from the battery?

Comment: @winny the 12v battery is supplying current to the field coils, but I have also set it up so it should be drawing some current from the armature too.

Comment: @JonathanS.they are drawing about an amp from the battery, will have a try with a capacitor and see what happens!

Comment: Quite the contrary to a capacitor, you probably need inductance.  They are both storage mechanisms, but inductance will behave more like momentum carrying mass whereas a cap more like a spring.  The key difference is the direction - you don't need spring back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out a universal motor can be considered to be a series DC motor.

A series DC motor has a low resistance coil which is optimized to reduce \$I^2R\$ losses with the coil carrying the full armature current. This means that it is usually made up of a few turns of thick wire and needs a lot of current to produce a good magnetic field. This contrasts with a shunt motor where the coil is lots of turns of thin wire and is designed to produce a good field with little current.

What this means is that your series motor which you have converted to a shunt motor is a poor choice to try to make a generator. The field coils will take so much current to produce a good field that the generator may never be self energizing.

Answer (score 1):

Old style generators have the same issue: the field coil needs to be pre-magnetized to give a startup flux.

Apply a DC current to the field separately. Make sure it’s the correct direction otherwise the output will be the wrong polarity.